# How to read message that has been replied to in telegram using telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telethon

I need to have script to read last message of telegram channel. If last message of this channel is reply to something I want to read that message what has last message answered to. For example highlighted message on this picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRSzS.jpg

I have this code to read last message but I have no idea how to read that message, I know I can use parameter is_reply to know if last message is reply to something but I don't know what to do next, any ideas?

```
async def get_mess():
    limit = 1
    global new
    async for message in client.iter_messages('Passive Lifestyle Forex Signals', limit):
        new = message.text

whlie True:
    get_mess()
```

I know it isn't most effective but that's not important. Any ideas how to code this? I can answer you if you need something more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [`get_messages`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html?highlight=get_messages#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.get_messages) to get the last message so you can also omit the limit. Then you'll need to check if the message is replying to an another message and if yes, get it.

```
   async def get_mess():
       global new
       message = await client.get_messages('YOUR CHAT') # you can omit the limit
       if message.is_reply:
           new = await message.get_reply_message()
   while True:
       get_mess()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async def get_mess():
    limit = 1
    global new
    async for message in client.iter_messages('Passive Lifestyle Forex Signals', limit):
        new = message
        if new.reply_to_msg_id:
            yourtext = await new.get_reply_message()

whlie True:
    get_mess()
```

Comment: This can be simplified by using `get_messages` to get rid of the loop. `get_reply_message` will also return `None` if there is no reply, so there is no need to check for `reply_to_msg_id`.